# Can I get the WCF Caller Url...?

Tags: .net, wcf

I have a WCF service that is called from various places

I have a method to get the ip and hostname of the caller.

But I was hoping to be able to get the full url of the caller if it's another service, aspx page, etc that is making the call.

Is that possible?

Currently what I have is essentially this:

```
public static string GetHostName()
{
    var hostName = "UNKOWN";

    try
    {
        var remoteEndpointMessageProperty = OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageProperties[RemoteEndpointMessageProperty.Name] as RemoteEndpointMessageProperty;
        hostName = remoteEndpointMessageProperty.Address;

        var hostEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(hostName);
        hostName = hostEntry.HostName;
    }
    catch
    {
    }

    return hostName;
}
```

Yes, I know the code is not currently clean (empty catch, etc), it's a proof of concept at the moment...

Comment: not unless you pass it explicitly as a message header or something like that...

Comment: What does it mean for the caller to "have" a URL? There is no such concept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not possible. All you can hope of getting is the IP address of the caller and of course any information contained in the request message and eventual HTTP headers.