# How to get the caller's URL in WCF netTcpBinding windows service?

Tags: c#, wcf, url, service, nettcpbinding

I need to get the calling app's URL because the service sends emails that contain links to my app (e.g. click here to view the form).

I'm considering just hard-coding the app's URL in 1 place on the service, but when working locally the local host port will sometimes change. Also, when deploying to different test environments I would have to change the URL. Also, working with others will pose a slight problem too.

The best solution would be to determine it dynamically. Second best, web.config. Third best: hard code it.

How can I resolve this and get the calling app's URL?

Edit: it's impossible to send the url from the client because the service has a timed event to send email notifications.

Comment: Does the caller necessarily _have_ a URL? If you need the URL, then have the caller send it to you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I get the WCF Caller Url...?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4147636/can-i-get-the-wcf-caller-url)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe the IP Can help

try this line

```
((RemoteEndpointMessageProperty)OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageProperties[RemoteEndpointMessageProperty.Name]).Address;
```

this article can help on the long way
http://keyvan.io/detect-client-ip-in-wcf-3-5

EDIT

getting the URL is not possible,

Similar question here
[Can I get the WCF Caller Url...?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4147636/can-i-get-the-wcf-caller-url)

Comment: How would the IP help? I need to a link similar to: http://www.myapp.com/forms?formId=123. I just need to know the www.myapp.com/ portion of the link.

Comment: well in that case getting the URL is not possible
Similar Question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4147636/can-i-get-the-wcf-caller-url

Comment: I figured as much: thanks. Could you put that in an official answer and I'll mark it as correct.